# A mollifier in 2D

Tags: functions, continuity

I have a domain $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

I want an explicit expression for a smooth function $\varphi$ on this domain that is zero on the boundary and $1$ in most of the interior, like a mollifier or bump function (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) .

I thought about something like $\varphi(x,y) = \exp(-1/(1-x^2-y^2))$ but it doesn't work... any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to first look at the 1-dimensional case, indeed if we have $f(x)=1$ on "most of" $[0,1]$ and vanishing at $0$ and $1$, then we can take $g(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$, which will be $1$ in "most of" $[0,1]$. Consider now the following function
$$f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto e^{\frac{-1}{1-x^2}+1}. $$
This function is 1 at 0 and it is 0 at 1, moreover, if extended to be 0 outside its domain, it turns out to be $C^\infty$. We want to take the image of $[0,1]$ and shrink it to fit into the small box $[1-\delta,1]$. Therefore we look a diffeomorphism between these two sets. Any would do the job, but we choose linear for simplicity:
$$ R:[1-\delta,1]\to [0,1], x\mapsto \frac{x}{\delta}+\frac{\delta-1}{\delta}. $$
The composition will take care of the right behavior of the sought function
$$ f\circ R = e^{\frac{-1}{1-\left( \frac{x}{\delta}+\frac{\delta-1}{\delta} \right)^2}+1} = e^{\frac{-\delta^2}{\delta^2-\left( x+\delta-1 \right)^2}+1}. $$
In a similar way, for the left side we want to map $[0,\delta]$ into $[1,0]$, where from $[1,0]$ I mean that the diffeomorphism must change the orientation. Again, we look for a linear form
$$ L:[0,\delta]\to [0,1],x\mapsto 1-\frac{x}{\delta}. $$
The left component for $f$ will be
$$ f\circ L = e^{\frac{-1}{1-\left( 1-\frac{x}{\delta} \right)^2}+1} = e^{\frac{-\delta^2}{\delta^2-\left( \delta-x \right)^2}+1}. $$
We can finally write
$$ f_\delta(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x\leq 0 \\
e^{\frac{-\delta^2}{\delta^2-\left( \delta-x \right)^2}+1} & x\in (0,\delta) \\
1 & x\in [\delta,1-\delta] \\
e^{\frac{-\delta^2}{\delta^2-\left( x+\delta-1 \right)^2}+1} & x\in (1-\delta,1) \\
0 & x\geq 1
\end{cases} $$
I created the following [script](https://ggbm.at/CPMfxyfz) using Geogebra, check it out.